# Cannot read text file in C++

Tags: c++

I am stumped by this simple problem. I am reading a text file with C++:

```
std::ifstream stream; 
stream.open(filename); 
if (!stream) 
   cout << "Invalid stream" << endl;
```

And `!stream` is true but there seems to be nothing wrong with the text file. Under what circumstances can `stream` be false?

**Note:** is_open returns true

Comment: Check for `is_open()`. Are you sure, `filename` is correct file path or, if it's just a file name - is the file inside the same dir, as the exe? For such questions, you must check the documentation..

Comment: post more code and your directory structure of the project

Comment: `is_open()` returns true

Comment: 3 seconds research - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operatornot/

Comment: Thanks for the above reference, but what is this failbit and badbit. The file opens fine in a text editor.

Comment: "*`is_open` returns true*" - In that case, I don't believe your observations. Please reduce your original program to the smallest possible program that demonstrates the error and copy-paste that into the question. See http://SSCCE.OrG for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;



int main()

{
    std::ifstream infilestream;
    std::string line;

    infilestream.open("test.txt");
    while(infilestream)
    {
      std::getline(infilestream, line);
      cout<<line<<"\n";
    }
    infilestream.close();

    return(0);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not provided enough information. Nevertheless, my psychic powers reveal:

`filename` is a relative path, and your current working directory is not what you think it is.

Inside your `if` clause, before printing via  `std::cout`, add this:

```
perror(filename.c_str());
```

Comment: is_open( ) returns true so no problem with filename

Answer (score 1):

chances are your file is inaccessible OR you might not have enough privileges to access the file.

Maybe its open somewhere else? Check if the path to the file is right.